# failed to call class

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

Game design : when the animal hit the hitbox, the game will be over.
When player click on the animal, player will gain point.

I have 3 scripts which is GameManager, PlayerDataClass, ScoreManager.

The playerDataClass is not attached to any object.
the code is as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class PlayerDataClass
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Name;
        }
        set
        {
            Name = value;
        }
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get
        {
            return Score;
        }
        set
        {
            Score = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateOfPlaying
    {
        get
        {
            return DateOfPlaying;
        }
        set
        {
            DateOfPlaying = value;
        }
    }

    // constructor
    public PlayerDataClass(string playerName, int playerScore)
    {
        Name = playerName;
        Score = playerScore;
        DateOfPlaying = DateTime.Today; // set the date to be current date
    }
}
```

I have attached the ScoreManager(Script) to the ScoreManager(GameObject). The aim of this code is to show player score.
The code is as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // create a reference based on PlayerDataClass
    public List<PlayerDataClass> testPlayer;

    void Start()
    {
      //cannot call showscore and setscore or not game will crush
    }

    void Init()
    {
        if (testPlayer != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // create the list of playerdataclass
        testPlayer = new List<PlayerDataClass>();
        testPlayer.Add(new PlayerDataClass("Harvey", 50)); //testing purpose
    }

    // used to show all the player score in the list
    public void ShowScore()
    {
        Init();

        // only call if the list is not equal to null
        if(testPlayer != null)
        {
            // loop through the list
            for (int i = 0; i <= testPlayer.Count; i++)
            {
                print(testPlayer[i].Name);
                print(testPlayer[i].Score);
                print(testPlayer[i].DateOfPlaying.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("the list is empty");
        }
    }

    // used to new player into the list
    public void SetScore(string playName, int playScore)
    {
        Init();

        // add new player with new score into the list
        testPlayer.Add(new PlayerDataClass(playName, playScore));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //cannot call showscore and setscore or not game will crush
    }
}
```

GameManager(Script) is attached to the GameManager(object). GameManager(Script) has boolen gameOver, which will pop out a game over menu to the user when the game is over. I will show the top 5 players result in this menu.

There is no Update() in the GameManager(Script).

GameManager(Script) is as below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;

    [HideInInspector]
    public List<GameObject> animalList = new List<GameObject>();

    // create player score list array to display
    // public List<PlayerDataClass> playerScoreList = new List<PlayerDataClass>();

    private int playerScore;

    // use to pause the game
    private bool gamePause = false;

    private bool gameOver = false;

    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;

    public AnimalSpawnner spawner;

    public GameObject gameOverPanel;

    public Button restartButton;

    // use to show individual score inside the score panel
    public TextMeshProUGUI showScoreText;

    // show score panel for individual
    public GameObject scorePanel;

    // public PlayerDataClass testPlayerPlayerData;

    // public ScoreManager testPlayer;

    // public GameObject scoreManager;

    public int PlayerScore
    {
        get
        {
            return playerScore;
        }

        set
        {
            playerScore = value;
            scoreText.SetText("Score: " + playerScore);
        }
    }

    public bool GameOver
    {
        get
        {
            return gameOver;
        }
        set
        {
            gameOver = value;

            if (gameOver)
            {
                gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);

                spawner.enabled = false;
                // playerScoreList.Add(new PlayerDataClass("James", 123));

                /*
                for(int i = 0; i < playerScoreList.Count; i++)
                {
                    print("my name is " + playerScoreList[i].Name);
                    print("my age is " + playerScoreList[i].Score);
                }
                */

                for (int i = 0; i < animalList.Count; i++)
                {
                    Destroy(animalList[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                gameOverPanel.SetActive(false);
                spawner.enabled = true;
                // Destroy(testPlayer); 
                //destroy score manager
            }
        }
    }

    public bool GamePause
    {
        get
        {
            return gamePause;
        }
        set
        {
            gamePause = value;

            // only pause game when it is not gameOver
            if(gameOver == false)
            {
                if (gamePause)
                {
                    spawner.enabled = false;

                    // if the game is pause, set spawned gameobject to be deactivate
                    for (int i = 0; i < animalList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        animalList[i].SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    scorePanel.SetActive(false);

                    for (int i = 0; i < animalList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        animalList[i].SetActive(true);
                    }

                    spawner.enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        instance = this;
        scoreText.SetText("Score: " + playerScore);
        restartButton.onClick.AddListener(OnClickRestart);
    }

    private void OnClickRestart()
    {
        GameOver = false;
    }
}
```

The animal has OnTriggerEnter2D function, which will trigger boolean gameOver when the animal hit the hitbox.
I tried to called ShowScore() function from ScoreManager in this part, the game crushed.

I failed to show the player score when the game over menu pop out.
I would like to ask, how should i implement my scoreManager function so that i can show the player score when the game over menu pop out ? Thank you.

Comment: Add your `GameManager` code!

Comment: @derHugo here you go

Answer (score 0):

**The problem are your Properties in `PlayerDataClass`!!**

Have a closer look on what happens here:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return Name;
    }
    set
    {
        Name = value;
    }
}

public int Score
{
    get
    {
        return Score;
    }
    set
    {
        Score = value;
    }
}

public DateTime DateOfPlaying
{
    get
    {
        return DateOfPlaying;
    }
    set
    {
        DateOfPlaying = value;
    }
}
```

Every time you read a properties value its getter is called; every time you assign a value to it its setter is called. Even then if this reading or assigning happens within these getter or setter itself.

Lets e.g. say you want to e.g. assign a value to `Name`.

So what happens is

```
set
{
    Name = value;
}
```

where again you assign a value to the property `Name` so it calls the setter of this property over and over again in an recursive endless loop! Basically what you did here equals a method call like

```
public void SetName(string value)
{
    SetName(value);
}
```

The same would happen for reading any of these properties since e.g.

```
get
{
    return Name;
}
```

equals a method like

```
public string GetName()
{
    return GetName();
}
```

The app crushes because you do this already in the constructor of `PlayerDataClass` so it doesn't matter in which method .. as soon as you call any `new PlayerDataClass(x, y)` the constructor causes an endless loop!

---

In your case you actually don't need any properties, you could instad just make it simple fields:

```
public class PlayerDataClass
{
    public string Name;
    public int Score;
    public DateTime DateOfPlaying;

    // constructor
    public PlayerDataClass(string playerName, int playerScore)
    {
        Name = playerName;
        Score = playerScore;
        DateOfPlaying = DateTime.Today; // set the date to be current date
    }
}
```

Using properties actually makes only sense if you a) want to implement some special behavior like value validation in the getter and/or setter or b) want to limit the access by e.g. only allow reading of a public propertie but assign the value only private. In all other cases you should rather simply use fields.

---

or **if** you want to use properties use either autoproperties (I'll use examples for show the limitations of access)

```
public class PlayerDataClass
{
    // this one can be assigned from any class also afterwards
    public string Name {get; set; }  

    // This one can be assigned afterwards but only from this class
    // e.g. via a method, it is read-only for any other class
    public int Score {get; private set; }

    // This one can only be assigned in the constructor of this class
    // and not be changed by anyone afterwards
    // it is read-only for any other class and this one except for the constructor
    public DateTime DateOfPlaying {get; }

    // constructor
    public PlayerDataClass(string playerName, int playerScore)
    {
        Name = playerName;
        Score = playerScore;
        DateOfPlaying = DateTime.Today; // set the date to be current date
    }
}
```

or use properties with backing field like (same access limitation examples as before)

```
public class PlayerDataClass
{
    private string name;     
    private int score;
    private DateTime dateOfPlaying;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Score
    {
        get { return score; }
        private set { score = value; }
    }

    public DateTime DateOfPlaying
    {
        get { return dateOfPlaying; }
    }

    // constructor
    public PlayerDataClass(string playerName, int playerScore)
    {
        name = playerName;
        score = playerScore;
        dateOfPlaying = DateTime.Today; // set the date to be current date
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the explaination, but I still can't understand why it end up an endless loop

Comment: @STREETKILLER007 ok so the thing with properties is: Everytime you e.g. assign a value to it, the setter is called. Everytime you read a properties value the getter is called. This happens even then if you read or assign the propertie within its own getter/setter. So basically this equals a recursive method call like `public void SetName(string name){ SetName(name); }` which now should make more obvious where the endless loop happens ;)

Comment: hmm, i understand it as since i have set method for every variable in PlayerDataClass.

so when i write new PlayerDataClass(James, 123)
, the setter for name and score, will be called for infinite time.

Comment: @STREETKILLER007 exactly! That is what happened. It was like a timebomb waiting for you assigning or reading any of these properties ;)

Comment: i am wondering if the variable are in PRIVATE, will the get or set will cause infinite loop ?

Comment: No because in the second property example using backing fields you are not getting and setting to the same property but rather from and to the backing fields which is only one call without any loop ;)

Comment: I am a bit confused on this whole reason "in the second property example using backing fields, you are not getting and setting to the same property but rather from and to the backing fields which is only one call without any loop“

Comment: @STREETKILLER007 well before you had e.g. `Name = value;` .. but `Name` is the property itself so this is where your recursive call was produced since again you call the setter of `Name` which again executes `Name = value;` ... With a backing field you instead assign the value to `name = value;` which is the backing field. It is a field so it has no further setter executed -> There is no recursion happening here.

Comment: hmm, i think i can understand it as like this.
PlayerDataClass(James, 123). 
When the code goes through the first time, Name = James. but i have setter for Name, so Name = James(endless loop here).

Comment: @STREETKILLER007 yes! As said instead use simple fields or properties but in the form of the last two examples, either as autoproperty or with a backing field. In your usecase it seems like you actually wouldn't want to be able to change these values later in which case you could use the form of e.g. `public string Name { get; }` which is only assignable from the constructor and otherwise read-only